# Trying to write a data into list from beautiful soup result every time even if no data found

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, beautifulsoup

Here is my problem I have a Beautiful soup code witch need to return email address or phone number but its don`t return anything.

```
for each in data_info:
            emails = re.findall('\S+@\S+',each.text)
            phone_num = re.findall('(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})', each.text)


            for each in emails:
                if('@' not in each):
                    email_is = False
                    data_info = soup.find_all('p')
                    for each in data_info:
                        emails = re.findall('\S+@\S+',each.text)
                        if('@' not in emails):
                            email_is = False
```

after this need to append data into list.Only one result per search.

```
            for email in emails:
            print(email)
            email_list.append(email)
            count += 1
            if(count >= 1):
                break
```

Comment: Mind sharing a sample HTML our a URL you're parsing?

Comment: https://www.altuzarra.com/en-bg/customer-service/contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need regex for that. You might be just fine with `bs4` and a `css` selector.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.altuzarra.com/en-bg/customer-service/contact").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
mailtos = soup.select('a[href^=mailto]')
print(list(set(m["href"] for m in mailtos)))
```

Output:

```
['mailto:careers@altuzarra.com', 'mailto:press@altuzarra.com', 'mailto:customerservice@altuzarra.com', 'mailto:sales@altuzarra.com']
```

And if you want "pure" emails, just change the last line to:

```
print(list(set(m["href"].replace("mailto:", "") for m in mailtos)))
```

To get this:

```
['customerservice@altuzarra.com', 'careers@altuzarra.com', 'press@altuzarra.com', 'sales@altuzarra.com']
```